# virtualenv can not work in centos and ubuntu

Tags: python, virtualenv

### Here is the example:

```
centos:(build a virtualen)
    $ virtualenv tenv

ubuntu:(active it)
    $ . tenv/bin/activate
    $ python
    Could not find platform independent libraries 
    Could not find platform dependent libraries 
    Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to [:]
    ImportError: No module named site
```

### In turn:

```
ubuntu:
    $ virtualenv ttenv

centos:
    $ . ttenv/bin/activate
    $ python
    ttenv/bin/python: /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by ttenv/bin/python)
    ttenv/bin/python: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by ttenv/bin/python)
    ttenv/bin/python: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.15' not found (required by ttenv/bin/python)
    ttenv/bin/python: /usr/lib64/libssl.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by ttenv/bin/python)
```

Answer (score 1):

What did you expect exactly ? Virtualenv creates a sandboxed Python environmenent with binaries etc **for the platform on which it's created** - it doesn't automagically makes the binaries platform-independent...

Comment: yeah, I had know how to use virtualenv across different OS with using **requirements.txt**